# Micro ROS with ESP32 keeps rebooting with and i2c sensor

Tags: micro-ros

I want to make a joint state publisher that publishes sensor data. So far I've been able to publish  joint_state with bogus data, however when I try to read data from i2c sensor something breaks. I'm using a TCA9548a i2c multiplexer to connect multiple sensors, but when I try to send the msg to the TCA9548a the ESP32 reboots and keeps rebooting. I can see that the micro ros agent is able to connect, and I can see the joint_state topic with ros2 topic list, but the micro ros agent keeps reconnecting and don't actually publish anything.

```
Wire.beginTransmission(0x70);
Wire.write(1 << 0);
Wire.endTransmission();
```

When I comment the communication with the TCA9548a It works fine and goes back to publishing the bogus data.
I'm using an ESP32 with micro ros arduino framework, ROS2 Humble and I'm communicating though wifi.
Is there any compatibility issue with i2c and micro ros at the moment?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide us with a log of the ROS launch? Also, can you try and get a debug trace of the ESP32? That will help you understand if the correct registers are being set.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. The Wire library has problems working with interrupts in the ESP32. Whenever I used `Wire.endTransmission();` the ESP32 would reboot. I updated the Arduino Core for ESP32 to the 2.0.14 and the problem is gone. The funny thing is that the ESP32 arduino implementation runs on top of FreeRTOS(that by nature has interrupts), and I had no problem using the Wire library with vanilla arduino code in the ESP32 in the past. The problem emerged when I used an interruption to acquire sensor data thru i2c and publish in a ros topic.